# Can I store my database online and access it through php for free?

Tags: database

I have a website designed in my laptop, php and javascript have been used. Installed Xampp and database is built in mysql it is accessed through php in my website. So, inorder to access this website I have to switch on my laptop. Can I take this entire system online. If yes, are there any free online hosting of database. Database only consists of text, No media.

Thank you, 
sailesh

Comment: yes.there are free hosting servers.you can use your pen-driver for that purpose but then it's only visible to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon web services offer 12 months of free tire. Give it a try.